# Looking for Wepawet-like open source alternative

Tags: malware, automated-testing

Is there any open source alternative to [Wepawet](http://wepawet.iseclab.org/) ? I need to study techniques of JavaScript malware detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're familiar with JSUnpack, it's a brilliant tool which has been made for the deobfuscation and detection of malicious javascript files.

It is open source, and available here: https://code.google.com/p/jsunpack-n/

Additionally, on top of javascript, it can scan the following file types:

- PDF files - samples/sample-pdf.file
- Packet Captures - samples/sample-http-exploit.pcap
- HTML files
- SWF files